# inheritance of static data

Tags: c#, inheritance, static

If have 3 classes:

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
 public static decimal IntrestRate { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class SavingsAccount  : BankAccount      
{
}

public class SightDeposit  : BankAccount      
{
}
```

Client code:

```
SavingsAccount.IntrestRate = 3.0M;
SightDeposit.IntrestRate = 1.0M;
--> will override the value of SavingsAccount.IntrestRate
```

So in need to implement it as follows

```
public abstract class BankAccount
    {
}

public class SavingsAccount  : BankAccount      
{
    public static decimal IntrestRate { get; set; }
}

public class SightDeposit  : BankAccount      
{
    public static decimal IntrestRate { get; set; }
}
```

thereby repeating IntrestRate in all derived classes :-(

Is there a way to define it once in the base-class but still make the program behave as it should ?

thank you

Chris

Comment: Why would you define InterestRate as static if you plan to have the value changed for child classes?

Comment: You've got a typo.  It should be "InterestRate".

Answer (score 3):

Remove the static modifier.

```
public abstract class BankAccount
{
    public decimal IntrestRate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: but IntrestRate is a specification that is not linked to any particular instance of BankAccount, it should the same for all BankAccounts, that's why it should be static no?